# How can I fail a test in TestNG in an AfterMethod?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I want to check some external log files after each test, if there were ary errors during execution. Throwing an exception in an `AfterMethod` doesn't work, because it is handled differently by TestNG: it will just fail the configuration method and not the preceding test.

My approach would be like this:

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
protected void tearDown(ITestResult result) {
    if (thereWasAProblemDuringTestExecution()) {
        result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
        result.setThrowable(getSomeThrowableSomebodyStoredAnywhere());
    }

    // doing other cleanUp-tasks
}
```

But still, my Eclipse TestNG plugin says the test passed.

Is it possible (and how) to fail a test (and not only a configuration method) in a configuration method?

Answer (score 2):

Try [setCurrentTestResult()](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Reporter.html#setCurrentTestResult%28org.testng.ITestResult%29) method from class org.testng.Reporter:

```
result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late but I can help anyone else who is looking for this.

You can do this using the ITestContext

For some reason you cant really update a result which is already generated. The workaround is to add the same result, remove it, update it then add it again. The only way I have found to remove a result is to do the add and remove sequence.

```
def testContext = Reporter.currentTestResult.testContext
testContext.passedTests.addResult(result,Reporter.currentTestResult.method)
testContext.passedTests.getAllMethods().remove(Reporter.currentTestResult.method)
result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE)
testContext.failedTests.addResult(result,Reporter.currentTestResult.method)
```

I am using Groovy.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide same above code in java ? Thanks!

Comment: I have tried to do following things in java - what I wanted to do is, if TCs failed (I retry two more time) then mark them as SKIP for first two FAILED CASE and last one also failed then report it as FAILED. Code: `ITestContext tc = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext();   tc.getFailedTests().getAllMethods().remove(Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod());
   result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
   tc.getSkippedTests().addResult(result,Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getMethod());` pls check