# How to fail a TestNG test immediately from another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, testng

I want to monitor external log files in separate threads in my Java testing framework:
if a specified pattern is found in one of those monitored log files, my test (running in the main thread) should fail immediately.

I tried to interrupt the thread my test runs in, but then I would have to check after each test step for `Thread.isInterrupted()`

Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a pretty terrible antipattern. Why are you monitoring log files in a unit test?

Comment: @Tom It's not in unit test, but in UI tests. If the SUT logs exceptions (and if these exceptions don't show up in the UI), I want to fail my test. Does it sound like an antipattern in this scenario too?

Comment: If an exception doesn't change the behavior of the UI such that the test fails, what good is the test?

Comment: @TomG Good point. It could happen that my test does what I expect it to do, but causes problems in other processes of my application. I can explicitly assert my expected results, but I don't know a way to be aware of side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can't remotely fail a test the way you want. Your idea about interrupting the threads is pretty much the right thing to do, except I'd avoid interruption and instead post an event to, say, [a `LinkedBlockingQueue` which you poll at the end of the test to see if it is empty or not](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#poll%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29).

If you want to avoid doing this in every test method, you can add the check in a method annotated with [`@AfterMethod`](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/AfterMethod.html).

Something like this:

```
public class YourTest {

 private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> errors;

 @BeforeMethod
 public void setUp() {
   errors = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
 }

 private void checkLogsForErrors(){
   // This is the method run in a separate thread.
   for (String line: iterateOverLogEntries()) {
     if (isError(line)) errors.add(line);
   }
 }

 @AfterMethod
 public void tearDown() {
   try {
     String error = errors.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     fail("Found error: " + error);
   } catch (InterruptedException e){
     // No errors, great!
   }
 }

}
```

**Edit:** Oh, right, *immediately*. Why not run the test code itself in a separate thread and have the original thread just waiting for either an error signal from the log watcher, or a success signal from the test?

Comment: I was afraid that wouldn't be possible and thought of this approach too! :) But a fail(...) in a tearDown would just fail a configuration method and not the whole test? (I asked this in a seperate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569671/how-can-i-fail-a-test-in-testng-in-an-aftermethod)

Comment: D'oh, that's rather useless. Well, you'd probably want to use a common method that starts the test and the log checker threads, so I suppose it might as well check the error queue as well...