# What is the usage of Reporter.SetCurrentTestResult in TestNG

Tags: testng

I am not able to understand the real need of Reporter.setCurrentTestResult() in TestNG. Will this statement show some result on the index.html.

Comment: This might help you :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569671/how-can-i-fail-a-test-in-testng-in-an-aftermethod

Comment: welcome Raj :) .....

Answer (score 0):

Basically the answer is yes. `Reporter.setCurrentTestResult()` will add current test results to HTML reports generated by TestNG.

But you need also use `Reporter.log()`, which is the main function to get something printed in your HTML reports. `Reporter.setCurrentTestResult()` is used additional information.

Comment: I tried by commenting out and uncommenting the line Reporter.setCurrentTestResult() but I could not find any difference. Please help me out understanding this. The code is as below:  public class Listener extends TestListenerAdapter implements IInvokedMethodListener{

 @Override
 public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
  
  Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);                                               }

Comment: public class Listener extends TestListenerAdapter implements IInvokedMethodListener{

 @Override
 public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult result) {
  
  Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);